# многомерный массив javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!
Имеется объект вида `items = {name0:[param00,param01],name1:[param10]}`(вообще получаем с json динамически).

Я вывожу имена:

```
for(name in items){    
    $('.all_projects').append('<div class="name">'+name+'</div><div class="tasks"></div>);
    };
```

Теперь, мне необходимо в `div.tasks` вывести соответственно `param` из массивов после `name`, я просто не могу понять как это сделать.

Если я вызываю:

```
for(name in items) {
 $('.all_projects').append('<div class="name">'+name+'</div><div class="tasks"></div>)
    for(val in items[name]) {
        $('.tasks').append(items[name][val])
    }
}
```

то получается бред, я понимаю что делаю не правильно, но где ?
need help please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var items = {
  name0: ["param00", "param01"],
  name1: ["param10"]
};

for (name in items) {
  console.log(items[name])
  for (let i = 0; i < items[name].length; i++) {
    console.log(items[name][i])
  }
}
```